# OpenTelemetry Context Propagation between grpc server/client writen in different languages

Tags: grpc, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

I have one Grpc server written in Go and Grpc clients written in Java/Python. What would be a good way to propagate opentelemetry context from server to client in this case?

Read about examples like https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/grpc-1.6/library#library-instrumentation-for-grpc-160, but seems it applies to server and client written in same programming languages.

Any thoughts, docs, or quick-start examples are appreciated.